# How Do I Pass HIdden HTML Value From One Page To Another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I know there are many variations of answers here but none that seem to fit my use case.  I'm using Django.....I am trying to pass a page number from one page to another when I click on an  tag.  I have defined the hidden input on both HTML pages...but can't seem to figure out how to get the value....

Here's my View...

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
    context['page_number'] = page_number
    return context
```

Here's my HTML...

First HTML Page

```
<form method="POST" id="forms">   
 <table>
   <td><a href="{% url 'Main:notify_update' pk=notify.id %}">{{ 
   notify.new_vacation_calendar.status }}</a></td>
   <input type="hidden" id="page_number" value="{{ page_number }}">
 </table>
</form>
```

The above renders correctly....

My second page....

```
<form method="POST">
 <button type="button" class="button67">Button</button>
 <input type="hidden" id="page_number">
</form>
```

My Javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
   $('.button67').on('click', function (event) {   
     var page = document.getElementById("page_number").value;
     console.log(page);    
   });
```

When I try to process the second page....the value isn't being passed and I can't figure out what I'm missing.  I'm used to passing values via the URL...but can't seem to figure out how to do this without using the URL.

Thanks in advance for any tips on what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: You don't seem to be submitting the form from your first page.

Comment: @mykaf Thanks for the feedback.  Fair point...but I'm intending for user to just be able to click on <a> tag and go to next page.  So I need to create a submit function so that the page is submitted in order to get the value?

Comment: @SteveSmith: why can't you just make a link with the page number and query parameters, searching is normally done through GET requests, not POST request, such that people for example can share the URL to someone else to obtain the same search results.

Comment: Then perhaps add a url variable to your `<a>` tag's `href` attribute and access that on the subsequent page. Your current code does nothing to send that data to the next page.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Thanks for the feedback.  Can you please show me an example of what you're saying?

Comment: @mykaf Can you please show me an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: Which page is your script on? `document.getElementById("page_number")` is on your first page and `$('.button67')` is on your second page, unless you are omitting some relevant code. You can't access both if they don't exist on the same page.

Comment: @mykaf Yeah that's why I'm a bit confused.  The document.getElementById("page_number") is on my first page and the second page is where I have the .button67 code....So they both need to be on the first page?

Comment: I'm not exactly even sure why you are trying to do this with separate function. I'm not familiar with django, but I think you could simply put the  `{{ page_number }}` into the `href` itself rather than try to use a function to do it.

Comment: @mykaf I tried to leverage page_number without a separate function but was unsuccessful.  The approach I'm using presently gets me the page number....but I just can't figure out how to pass it to the next page.  It won't retain the value...it just retains the reference.

Comment: *I tried to leverage page_number without a separate function but was unsuccessful.*: what specifically did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: @mykaf I tried something like...<td><a href="{% url 'Main:notify_update' pk=notify.id %}" data-id="{{ page_number }}"><h2 class="spacer6">{{ notify.new_vacation_calendar.status }}</h2></a></td>  This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255040/discussion-between-mykaf-and-steve-smith).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @mykaf for pointing me in the right direction.  I ultimately leveraged the page_number on the first page and added it to the URL as shown below...

```
<td><a href="{% url 'Main:notify_update' pk=notify.id %}?page={{ page_number }}"></a></td>
```

This allowed me to leverage it on the next page.